# Request to swagger api with postman does not have body

Tags: javascript, swagger, postman, swagger-2.0

I am making a request via postman to a swagger api, sending a body parameter. The problem is that in the api I cannot retrieve that parameter. Both req.body or req.swagger.params.body are undefined. In fact I've checked every property of the request object and the body is not there.

Is something wrong in my postman request or the swagger definition?

The request in postman:

Postman auto-genarated http code:

```
POST /myUrl/
Host: 127.0.0.1:10010
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx
{
    "username": "user2",
    "password": "pass2"
}------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Postman auto-generated curl code:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://127.0.0.1:10010/users/ \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: f8c71ed0-6ef1-4dcf-b1b6-a7f2777a759e' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "username": "user2",
    "password": "pass2"
}'
```

The endpoint definition in swagger:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: XXXXX
host: 127.0.0.1:10010
basePath: /
schemes:
  - http
  - https
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
tags:
  - name: xxx
    description: Endpoints callable by the xxx
paths:
  /users/:
    x-swagger-router-controller: user.controller
    post:
      tags:
        - xxx
      summary: Create a new user
      description: Create a new user
      operationId: createUser
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: user
          description: The user to create
          schema:
            type: object
            required:
              - username
              - password
            properties:
              username:
                type: string
              password:
                type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/CreateUserResponse'
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show an image of what that looks like in Postman please?

Answer (score 1):

That `------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--` seems wrong.

Either your Content-Type is `multipart/mixed; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--` and use the boundary to separate form encoded parameters.

Or your Content-Type is `application/json` and you send json which doesn't require a boundary.

But as your swagger consumes `application/json`, make sure you remove the `------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--` from the body.

Comment: Where should I remove that in postman? That WebKitFormBoundary only appears in the auto-generated http sample code. I added the curl sample where it does not appear

Comment: I have no idea how it creeped into your postman request. Do you get a 200 response?